# Парсинг несколько запросов одновременно

Tags: php, классы, парсер

Здравствуйте! есть задача, надо спарсит несколько разных запросов одновременно.
Вопрос: возможно есть какой нибудь быстрый готовый класс на php, если есть можно с примером показать работу класса? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:
http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/client.html#sending-requests-in-parallel

For an easy to use solution that returns a hash of request objects mapping to a response or error, see http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/batching/batching.html#batching

Short example:

```
<?php

$client->send(array(
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/foo'),
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/baz'),
    $client->get('http://www.example.com/bar')
));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520185/how-to-perform-multiple-guzzle-requests-at-the-same-time